# Reduce the count in file upload input field

Tags: jquery

What I am trying to figure out is reduce the count when a file is removed by the user (Please refer the image below).

[image: image link]

Currently, I have a script that generates a preview of the images followed by the name of the images. What I am trying to achieve is when the user decides to remove an image, the count goes down by one or more, depending on how many images were removed.

Currently, I am able to count how many images are displayed which is how I show or hide the Remove All Images button, but not been able to figure out how to reduce the count and display how many files are still selected. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
/*Upload Image and Preview in form*/
//When user clicks on Remove All Images Button
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#delete_all").click(function(){
        $(".pip").remove();
        $("#delete_all").hide();
        $('#files').val('');
    });
    //Checks how many images still in form and whether 
    //Remove All Images button should be displayed
    $(document).on("click", ".remove", function(){
        if($(".pip").length > 1)
            $("#delete_all").show();
        else
            $("#delete_all").hide();
    });
    //If clear button is clicked, hides Remove All Images button
     $(document).on("click", "#clear", function(){
        if($(".pip").length < 1)
            $("#delete_all").hide();
    });
    //Process to upload and Preview Images being uploaded
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
        $("#files").on("change", function(a) {
            var files = a.target.files,
            filesLength = files.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
                var f = files[i]
                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.fileName = files[i].name;
                fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
                    var file = e.target;
                    if(filesLength > 1){
                        $("<div class=\"pip\">" +
                        "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" + 
                        "<br />" + "<span class=\"fontImage\">" + file.fileName + "</span><br/><span class=\"remove\">x</span>" + "</div>").insertAfter("#files");
                    }
                    else{
                        $("<div class=\"pip\">" +
                        "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" + 
                        "<br />" + "<span class=\"remove\">x</span>" + "</div>").insertAfter("#files");
                    }
                    $(".remove").on('click', function(){
                        $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
                        if($(".pip").length < 1){
                            $('#files').val('');
                        }
                    });
                    if($(".pip").length > 1)
                        $("#delete_all").show();
                    else
                        $("#delete_all").hide();
                });             
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
            }
       });
    } 
    // /*else {
        //alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API.");
    // }*/
});
/***********************/
```

The following is where I adding the images

```
<fieldset>
    <legend><span class="number">3</span> Image Attachment (Optional)</legend>
    <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" />
    <input type="button" class="button small-btn" value="Remove All Image" id="delete_all" style="display:none;"/>
</fieldset>
<input onclick="return checkForm(this.form);" type="submit" value="Submit" />
<input onclick="return resetForm(this.form);" type="reset" value="Clear" id="clear" />
```

**UPDATE:** I was able to create my own upload images and hide the html input file field. However, I am unable to figure out to increment or reduce the count. This is what I have so far:

```
    <div class="backgroundColor">
        <div style="float: left">
          <a id="fileupload" class="create-btn-file no-style">Chose Files</a>
        </div> 
        <div class="textStyle">
          <span id="replaceText">No file chosen</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="file" id="files" class="reduceMargin" name="files[]" multiple />

    /*Anchor Tag acts like the input file tag*/
      $("#fileupload").click(function(){
         $("#files").click();
      });
```

The following is the css that gives the anchor tag a button feel look:

```
    /*Create my own 'Choose Files input file button'*/
#files{
    display:none;
}
.no-style {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #8a97a0;
}
/*.no-style:hover{
    color: #8a97a0;
}*/
.create-btn-file {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.create-btn-file{
    display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: #e8eeef;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  border:1px solid #D3D3D3; 
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
.textStyle{
    color: #8a97a0;
  margin-left: 14px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.reduceMargin{
    margin-bottom:0px !important
}
.backgroundColor{
    background: white;
    height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding-top: 3px;
}
/***********/
```

Comment: Could you please provide the relevant HTML?

Comment: @callback: I have added the relevant HTML. Thank you for your help

Comment: Where in the HTML do you have the text "`numberOfFiles` files" that appears next to the file input?

Comment: @callback: I do not have that I believe it is generated by the type and multiple that is in the input. Does that mean I would need to create my a input type field of my own?

Comment: Hmm, the problem with the default browser's file input, is that the text next to the button is hard coded, and getting around it is very challenging.. One workaround i can think about is to use another text somewhere (maybe even on top of the other text) and manipulate those numbers there. For example, when the user choses the images the first time, you can get the total number of files, and whenever he deletes/adds, you increase/decrease the number, and show it in the"other" text field.. How does it sound?

Comment: @callback: That does sound good but it sounds like in the process of doing that, I will be hiding the input field. In doing so, I feel it would cause issue if the user decided to uploaded another image(s).

Comment: Question: If I would to do that, how would i hide the count for the input file field? would it be '$(''#file).val('')' and if so, how would I change the text "No file Choosen" and replace it with blank until the count is 0?

Comment: @callback: can you please provide an example on how to achieve this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166868/discussion-between-callback-and-roberto-flores).